# Is the graph minicut with the node cardinality constraint NP-hard?

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, computational-complexity

I wonder whether the following problem is a well-studied NP-hard problem?

Get a graph $G$ and a number $k$, we partition the graph $G$ into two components where each component should have at most $k$ vertices and the number of edges in the cut is minimal.

**In other words, is the mini-cut problem with the vertex budget constraint NP-hard?**

Thanks.

Comment: How many vertices does $G$ have and are there lower bounds on the vertices in each component?

Comment: No, there are not lower bounds on the vertices in each component. You can assume that the number of vertices of $G$ is $n$.

Comment: Since we're looking for a bipartition, upper bounds on the part sizes are exactly the same as lower bounds.

Answer (score 1):

Min-cut with bounded part sizes is the same as max-cut with bounded part sizes on the complement.  Given any graph $H$ for which we would like to know the max-cut, form a new graph $G$ by adding $|H|$ isolated vertices.  Then the max-cut of $G$ with bounded part sizes is the max-cut of $H$, with the part sizes balanced out using the isolated vertices.  So max-cut can be reduced to max-cut (or min-cut) with bounded part sizes, and your problem in NP-hard.

Comment: Could you elaborate your first claim? I imagine something like that to be true, but don't see the exact correspondence.

Comment: @smpapers, you're right, that only works if the parts are balanced rather than bounded -- if the partition is into parts of size as equal as possible then they're equivalent because the total number of possible crossing edges is fixed.  Happily the reduction I sketch is to balanced max-cut, and so balanced min-cut, which is a special case of bounded min-cut (so the general case is still NP-hard).

Comment: Great, I agree.